# Does a Timer object continue firing after app transitions from suspended to background state?

Tags: ios, swift

Say I have Timer, it runs while the app is in foreground and a brief period after the application is put into the background and then stops when the app enters suspended state.
If for instance a significant location update wakes the app moving it to background state will the timer start firing or will it only start again if the app goes to foreground?

Comment: I don't think app can go from suspend to background state directly. Correct me id I'm wrong.

Comment: An app can go from suspended to background execution exactly as @iOSDevZ explains in the question; a location update event can trigger background execution as can other background events if your app is using them

Comment: I believe the timer will fire in the background, but your background execution in response to a location update is typically a fraction of a second or a couple of seconds at most, so you may not get many timer ticks, depending on its interval